# Exception when I run a hadoop job in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, launch

I am trying to run a Hadoop wordcount job (I am using hadoop 2.6.0). When I export my project to runnable jar and run it from CLI it works. However when I launch it in Eclipse with "Run as java application" I receive the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.(Configuration.java:173)
>       at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:54)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 2 more

Can anybody assist me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not properly configured Eclipse and it doesn't know where to find the Apache Commons libraries jars. From [this tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment), you may be missing the last steps:

> To run tests from Eclipse you need to additionally do the following:
>
> - Under project Properties, select Java Build Path, and the Libraries tab
> - Click "Add External Class Folder" and select the build directory of the current project

You may also want to take a look at [this other tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/running-hadoop-mapreduce) where it shows how/where to add the dependencies jars to run a Hadoop program.

Comment: Actually i have added the JARs under /usr/local/hadoop/share/common and JARs under /usr/local/hadoop/mapreduce/ but it doesn't work

Comment: Try mvn install. See https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/BUILDING.txt "Importing projects to eclipse".

Answer (score 0):

You should add ***commons-logging-1.1.1.jar*** to your eclipse project and rebuild again.

Comment: This JAR(commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ) dosen't exist under my Hadoop folder , i am using hadoop 2.6.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Please add all .jar in `/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added jars from ***usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/bin***

Add all the jars in this:
[image: Add all the jars in this]

This solved my problem when I am running a MapReduce program directly from eclipse.